# Linked services does not appear in Azure data factory

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, linked-service

I am executing the

```
az datafactory linked-service create
```

command, which creates a new linked service in my ADF. It is visible. However, after integrating ADF with Git, the same command returns information about the created Linked Service, but it is not visible in the GUI. This is strange to me because the

```
az datafactory linked-service list
```

command shows Linked Services from my branch, including the newly created one.

What am I doing wrong?

Expect:

Linked services will appear in an Adf with a Git integation after execute

```
az datafactory linked-service create
```

Answer (score 1):

- You are not able to view any of the linked services is because you are creating the linked services in datafactory live more, listing the linked services in live mode but trying to find these linked services in GIT mode.
- I have created a linked service using the below command:

```
 az datafactory linked-service create --factory-name "df240523" --properties "{\"type\":\"AzureStorage\",\"typeProperties\":{\"connectionString\":{\"type\":\"SecureString\",\"value\":\"DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=blb240523;AccountKey=<account_key>\"}}}" --name "blob1" --resource-group "<resource_grp>"
```

[image]

- When I list these, I will be able to see the above create linked service:

```
az datafactory linked-service list --factory-name "df240523" --resource-group "v-sarikontha-Mindtree"
```

[image]

- But, as you can see, the above created linked service is not visible in the git mode/branch.

[image]

- But when I navigate to Git configuration -> import resources, and then refresh the factory in git mode, I am able to view the changes and the created linked service in UI as well.

[image]

- The following is the UI image for reference:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, it wokrs. But it looks weird.